# Scatter non-square matrix

Tags: matlab

I would like to scatter matrix of any dimensions (height, width, depth). The problem is that scatter takes matrices of equal dimensions.
Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

I was thinking about complementing my matrix to square one and then minimizing the size and color of those points that are "virtual", but I'm trying to find a better solution.
Can anyone help?

Here is the way I intend this to work:

```
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:height, 1:widht, 1:depth);
scatter3(x(:), y(:), z(:), size, data_matrix(:));
```

To show purpose of this code: Say, I have temperature in a room stored in a matrix. I want to plot the temperature in a 3D plot. If there is a better way to achieve this then scatter (which seems to work for [equal dimensions case](http://snag.gy/yaSJb.jpg)), will be grateful to know it :D

Comment: Think about a 2-dimensional case. What would it mean to scatterplot a 2-by-1 matrix? There would only be one second-dimension-value for each first-dimension-value, so the plot would be degenerate for all points. The same happens for higher dimensions. If you only supply data along each axis for which you also have corresponding values along the other axes (that is, the only points you'd care about plotting) then your arrays will be square.

Comment: Unless you are trying to use the indices of your arrays as the first two scatter dimensions and the value at entry (i,j) as the third dimension, like a mesh. But then this is not a scatter plot.

Comment: As far as I know ,scatter plot accepts vectors, not matrices, so I guess I don't understand what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: My guess is the OP either intends a meshgrid kind of plot, or is mixing up meshgrid syntax with scatter syntax.

Comment: @natan, added the sample code... and I am plotting matrix.

Comment: You want to use `surf` not `scatter`. You should not use the output of `meshgrid` (which is intended to depict function values plotted "above" grid values) as a way to plot scatters (which intends to plot unordered tuples of associated data).

Comment: I guess `surf` won't work as I want to show data about 3D space. When it comes to `surf` it must have been 4D plot to show this data (I think so).

Comment: Added the aim I want to reach to the question. Is there a way to plot values of matrix in a 3D space other then scatter with scatter's visibility?

Comment: I think you are using `surf` incorrectly. Its primary use is for 3D data, not 4D (how would you visualize 4D?? as a video? surely not with `surf`).

Comment: Every point has 3 dimensions and 1 "temperature" value. So it has "4 dimensions". What scatter does is it prints this 4th variable as point color. Is there a way to achieve something like this the other way?